# MySQL joining table to itself and comparing results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

MySQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15d447/1

I have a single table I am trying to work with:

Table 1: `user_answers` table (stores users answers to various questions)

The notable values that are stored are the users id (column `uid`), the question id for the question they are answering (column `quid`), the answer to the question (column `answer`) and the importance of their answer (column `importance`).

The end result I want:

I'd like to be able to grab all the questions that any two users have answered, excluding any answers from questions that have either not been answered by the other party, or answers to the same question which have a value of 1 for either user in `importance`.  Again, this will only ever be used to compare two users at a time.

I've been pretty unsuccesful in my attempts, but here is what I've tried, just piecing things together:

```
#attempt one: trying to exclude answers that were not answered by both users
SELECT * FROM user_answers AS uid1
JOIN user_answers AS uid2 ON uid1.uid = uid2.uid
WHERE uid1.uid = 1
AND uid2.uid = 20008
AND uid1.quid IS NOT NULL
AND uid2.quid IS NOT NULL;
```

This returns no results but I'm not exactly sure why.

```
#attempt two: trying to exclude where answers are the same for both users
SELECT * FROM user_answers AS uid1
LEFT JOIN user_answers AS uid2 ON (uid1.uid = uid2.uid AND uid1.answer <> uid2.answer)
```

This gives me results, but seems to be doubling up on everything because of the join.  I also tried in this attempt to eliminate any answers what were the same, which seems to be working in that sense.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 . . . How can one not upvote a question that starts "My SQL Fiddle is here"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer your question using an aggregation query.  The idea is to using the `having` clause to filter the rows for the conditions you are looking at.

Because you are not interested at all in questions with `importance = 1` those are filtered using a `where` clause:

```
select ua.quid
from user_answers ua
where importance <> 1 and uid in (1, 20008)
group by ua.quid
having sum(uid = 1) > 0 and
       sum(uid = 20008) > 0;
```

If you want to include the answers, you can do:

```
select ua.quid,
       group_concat(concat(uid, ':', answer) order by uid) as answers
```

Comment: Nice way of avoiding the join indeed. I'd personally rather have the answer of both parties as separate columns though, `GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=1,answer,'') SEPARATOR '') as a1, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=1,answer,'') SEPARATOR '') as a2`

Comment: Oh, BTW, for 2 users one could also have a `COUNT(distinct uid) = 2` instead of the 2 `SUM`'s

Comment: @cjaredrun . . . You are missing a comma after `quid` in the `select` statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff a bit embarrassed that I missed this, but after running the query on a larger data set i realized that I wasn't excluding the results where the two users had answered the same.

You'll notice here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15d447/25 that quid 2 is answered the same. I attempted to add `WHERE a1 <> a2` on the same line as the group_concat as well as `AND a1 <> a2` after the initial `WHERE` but was unable to get that to work. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @cjaredrun . . . I suggest that you ask another question.

Comment: that's fair, thanks.  New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695368/mysql-comparing-and-excluding-results-properly

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple version of what you need.

```
select *
 from user_answers a,
      user_answers b
where a.quid = b.quid
  and a.uid <> b.uid
  and 1 not in (a.importance, b.importance)
```

If you like to filter just the questions just change the `*` for `distinct a.quid`

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15d447/15