# MySQL comparing and excluding results properly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

MySQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15d447/25

I have a single table I am trying to work with:

Table 1: user_answers table (stores users answers to various questions)

The notable values that are stored are the users id (column `uid`), the question id for the question they are answering (column `quid`), the answer to the question (column `answer`) and the importance of their answer (column `importance`).

The end result I want:

I'd like to be able to grab all the questions that any two users have answered, excluding any answers from questions that have either not been answered by the other party, answers that are identical between the two, or answers to the same question which have a value of 1 for either user in importance. Again, this will only ever be used to compare two users at a time.

Thus far I have been able to get the results, and answers for the two users with all of my conditions except excluding answers they have both answered the same.  In the sqlfiddle example you will see both users answered quid 2 with the answer 'aa'. The desired result would exclude quid 2 and only return quid 1.

The query I am currently using is this:

```
select ua.quid,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=1,answer,'') SEPARATOR '') as a1, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=20008,answer,'') SEPARATOR '') as a2
from user_answers ua
where importance <> 1 and uid in (1, 20008)
group by ua.quid
having sum(uid = 1) > 0 and
       sum(uid = 20008) > 0;
```

With this query I attempted to add `WHERE a1 <> a2` on the same line as the group_concat as well as `AND a1 <> a2` after the initial `WHERE` but was unable to get that to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I think I understand it.

If the users have only one answer for each question, then this should work:

```
select ua.quid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=1,answer,'') SEPARATOR '') as a1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=20008,answer,'') SEPARATOR '') as a2
from user_answers ua
where importance <> 1 and uid in (1, 20008)
group by ua.quid
having sum(uid = 1) > 0 and
       sum(uid = 20008) > 0 and
       max(case when uid = 1 then answer end) <> max(case when uid = 20008 then answer end);
```

EDIT:

Of course, users *can* have multiple answers.  This is pushing me toward a `join` approach rather than an aggregate-only approach.  Unfortunately, such an approach needs a `full outer join`, which MySQL does not support.  So, let's try aggregating by answer, first.  You only have two users, so we'll pivot the values:

```
select ua.quid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(user1 > 0, answer, '') SEPARATOR '') as a1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(user20008 > 0, answer, '') SEPARATOR '') as a2
from (select ua.quid, ua.answer,
             max(case when ua.uid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as user1,
             max(case when ua.uid = 20008 then 1 else 0 end) as user20008
      from user_answers ua
      where importance <> 1 and ua.uid in (1, 20008)
      group by ua.quid, ua.answer
     ) t
where t.user1 = 0 or t.user20008 = 0
group by ua.quid;
```

Comment: In my particular use case the users won't be able to have more than one answer per question so the first example seems to solve that (tested it on real data), but the second example gives me a lot to think about/research, if only for the methods you're using.

Appreciate the guidance.

Comment: out of curiosity, how come comparing the aliases a1 and a2 like `where a1 <> a2` does not work in this case?

Comment: @cjaredrun . . . I think the answer is that the `where` clause does not understand column aliases in the `select` clause at the same level.  You need to use a subquery (or use the MySQL extension that allows a `having` clause to do this in this case).

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to grasp that.  I am playing with another experiment where I think I might be relying on `having` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715005/convoluted-comparisons-and-exclusions-inside-a-single-mysql-table

I'm adding a few more variables into the mix and looking for conflicts among them.  I know I may be boring you, but I appreciate your insights so far.