# Convoluted comparisons and exclusions inside a single MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

MySQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6094e8/6

The fiddle contains the data that goes along with my examples below.

I have a single table I am trying to work with:

Table 1: user_answers table (stores users answers and their acceptable asnwers to various questions)

The notable values that are stored are:

users id (column `uid`)
question id for the question they are answering (column `quid`)
answer to the question (column `answer`)
acceptable answer storage #1 stores other acceptable answers for that user (column `acceptable_1`)
acceptable answer storage #2 stores other acceptable answers for that user (column `acceptable_2`)
acceptable answer storage #3 stores other acceptable answers for that user (column `acceptable_3`)
acceptable answer storage #4 stores other acceptable answers for that user (column `acceptable_4`)
importance of their answer (column `importance`)

The answer column will store a value between 1 and 4.

The acceptable columns hold selected acceptable answers which are in line with their column placement.  For example, user 1 answers 1, but would accept answers 2 and 3.  This would make `acceptable_2 = 2` and `acceptable_3 = 3`, leaving `acceptable_1` and `acceptable_2` with a value of 0.

For the sake of example I'll try and explain the results I am looking for:

**Example 1:**
User 1 answers 3 on quid 1 and would accept answers 2 and 4 from another user for that same question.

User 2 answers 2 on quid 1 and would accept answers 3 from another user for that same question

**Result for Example 1:**
User 1 would accept user 2's answer and user 2 would accept accept user 1's answer. This result should be excluded from the results.

**Example 2:**
User 1 answers 2 on quid 2 and would accept answers 1 or 4 from another user for that same question.

User 2 answers 2 on quid 2 and would accept answers 2 or 4 from another user for that same question.

**Result for Example 2:**
User 1 would not accept user 2's answer, but user 2 would accept user 1's answer. This comparison has a single conflict in it and should be included in the results.

**Example 3:**
User 1 answers 1 on quid 3 and would accept answers 1 or 2 from another user for that same question.

User 2 answers 1 on quid 3 and would accept answers 1 or 2 from another user for that same question.

**Result for Example 3:**
User 1 would accept user 2's answer and user 2 would accept user 1's answer. There is no conflict and this result should be excluded from the results.

**Example 4:**
User 1 answers 1 on quid 4 and would accept answers 1 or 2 from another user for that same question.

User 2 answers 3 on quid 4 and would accept answers 3 or 4 from another user for that same question.

**Result for Example 4:**
User 1 would not accept user 2's answer and user 2 would not accept user 1's answer. There are two conflicts and this result should be included in the results.

As I hope is visible, I would like to grab the `quid` for the questions both users have answered which have conflict in their answers in terms of what is in the other users acceptable columns.

So far I have been able to gather the answers and acceptable answers for each user using this query:

```
select ua.quid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=1,answer,'') SEPARATOR '') as a1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=2,answer,'') SEPARATOR '') as a2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=1,acceptable_1,'') SEPARATOR '') as ac1_1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=1,acceptable_2,'') SEPARATOR '') as ac2_1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=1,acceptable_3,'') SEPARATOR '') as ac3_1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=1,acceptable_4,'') SEPARATOR '') as ac4_1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=2,acceptable_1,'') SEPARATOR '') as ac1_2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=2,acceptable_2,'') SEPARATOR '') as ac2_2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=2,acceptable_3,'') SEPARATOR '') as ac3_2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(uid=2,acceptable_4,'') SEPARATOR '') as ac4_2
from user_answers ua
where importance <> 1 and uid in (1, 2)
group by ua.quid
having sum(uid = 1) > 0 and
       sum(uid = 2) > 0
```

Not being able to use the aliases I use to house the acceptable answers for each user in my WHERE clause (ac1_1, etc), I have yet to successfully compare all the variables to get the expected results.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Can `Table 1` have information for **more** than 2 users?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes it will store information for several users, but we will only ever be comparing two users at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this (using `SELF JOIN`):

```
SELECT t1.quid, t1.uid As u1, t2.uid As u2
FROM user_answers t1
JOIN user_answers t2 ON t1.uid > t2.uid AND t1.quid = t2.quid AND
     (FIELD(t1.answer, t2.acceptable_1, t2.acceptable_2, t2.acceptable_3, t2.acceptable_4) = 0  OR
      FIELD(t2.answer, t1.acceptable_1, t1.acceptable_2, t1.acceptable_3, t1.acceptable_4) = 0 )
WHERE t1.importance <> 1 AND t2.importance <> 1 and t1.uid in (1, 2) AND t2.uid in (1, 2);
```

As you can see, question to answers comparison is done with [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function.

Here's [your **Fiddle** with my code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6094e8/17).